# Warn user on entering different numbers in do while loop

Tags: java, do-while

Just wondering how I could prompt the user when they enter numbers greater to 5 or less than 0.

It prompts when they enter letters but when they enter different numbers it only repeats the "Enter a Given number: "

```
outer:
        do {

            
            try {
                System.out.println("Starting in 3 seconds...");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("Select the Number for the program you would like to use");
                Thread.sleep(700);
                System.out.println("Enter '1', For BMI (Body Mass Index)");
                Thread.sleep(600);
                System.out.println("Enter '2', For The Area of Triangle");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                System.out.println("Enter '3', For The Area of Square");
                Thread.sleep(400);
                System.out.println("Enter '4', For The Area of Rectangle");
                Thread.sleep(300);
                System.out.println("Enter '5', For Finding Odd/Even Number");
                Thread.sleep(200);
                System.out.println("Enter '0' to exit");
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            int user_selection=0;
            do {
                System.out.print("Enter a given number: ");
                while (!user_input.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println("That's not a number");
                    System.out.print("Please Enter only the Number Given: ");
                    user_input.next();
                }
                user_selection = user_input.nextInt();
            } while (user_selection <= 5 || user_selection>5 || user_selection<0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `user_selection` should be between 0 and 5? Then remove  `user_selection <= 5`

```
while (user_selection>5 || user_selection<0);
```

Comment: it works but I want to warn the user when they enter different number because in this case it only repeats the line System.out.print("Enter a given number: ");

Output: 
Select the Number for the program you would like to use
Enter '1', For BMI (Body Mass Index)
Enter '2', For The Area of Triangle
Enter '3', For The Area of Square
Enter '4', For The Area of Rectangle
Enter '5', For Finding Odd/Even Number
Enter '0' to exit
Enter a given number: 600
Enter a given number:

Answer (score 0):

I really didnt get your approach of the code so here is my idea of how i would handle it. Im personally not a fan of do while as they are not really good to read but thats personal perference. Be aware that i could not test that code as i never work with java

```
System.out.println("Starting now...");
System.out.println("Select the Number for the program you would like to use");
System.out.println("Enter '1', For BMI (Body Mass Index)");
System.out.println("Enter '2', For The Area of Triangle");
System.out.println("Enter '3', For The Area of Square");
System.out.println("Enter '4', For The Area of Rectangle");
System.out.println("Enter '5', For Finding Odd/Even Number");
System.out.println("Enter '0' to exit");

boolean acceptedAnswer = false;
int user_selection=0;

while(!acceptedAnswer){
    System.out.print("Enter a given number: "); 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //block until input is given
    String s = scanner.nextLine();
    user_selection = Integer.parseInt(s);
    if(user_selection <= 5 && user_selection>=0){
        System.out.println("VALID INPUT");
        acceptedAnswer = true;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("That's not a valid input");   
    }
}


//when answer is accepted we go here
//if(user_selection == 1){
// do something
//}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).